# Does tc (traffic constrol) work with packets or frames?

Tags: linux, networking, traffic

Assume we are working with TCP/IP connection.

According to https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/kernel_flow `tc` works on Layer 2. However, everywhere else in the internet term "packet" is used to describe the units of data that `tc` works with.

What does tc actually work with - `Packets` or `Frames`?

Answer (score 0):

Traffic control (also called Quality of Service) can be performed at layer 2 or layer 3 or both.  Remember that  layers are an abstract concept, so when applied to actual hardware/software, things can get a little murky.

Comment: Let's say, I set up a single PRIO qdisc for network interface `eth0` and want to queue data flowing from my application to different priority classes depending on the source port. Will the PRIO qdisc work with packets or frames?

Comment: How do I define the layer I want to work at?

Comment: Are you talking about physical ports or TCP/UDP ports?

Comment: `TCP/UDP` ports. I have an application that sends different data on separate ports. I want to perform prioritisation of this data wih help of `tc`. In my case it is important to work with frames and not packets, because I need the higher-prio data to be sent as soon as possible and not wait for the big low-prio packet to be sent completely

Comment: There are (at least) two parts to QoS:  Classifying and scheduling.  Scheduling probably falls at layer 2.

Comment: In that case, you're classifying at layer 4.  But scheduling is layer 2

Comment: If a big frame is being transmitted, you'll have to wait for it to be completed.  You can't interrupt an Ethernet frame.

Comment: That means I classify TCP segments with help of filters, which use source port as their decision-criteria, then it goes through IP stack, reaches the qdisc at Layer 2 already in form of frames and the PRIO qdiscs enqueues frames..?

Comment: What do You mean under "big frame"? Aren't they all of same size? (1500 bytes per default)

Comment: 1500  is the max size, they can be as small as 64 bytes.

Comment: "moving through" layers is an imaginary process.  Packets are classified, routed to an interface, encapsulated in a frame, then queued for transmission.  Scheduling affects which queue gets serviced first.

Comment: Ok. Let us assume the following situation: A big packet (say 100Kbytes) comes from `low-prio` source. The packet is divided into many frames, which get classified to an appropriate queue. The transmission starts and then the `high-prio` packet is generated. It gets  classified to appropriate high-priority queue and needs to be sent asap. Do the frames of this `high-prio` data get transmitted as soon as they arrive or must they wait until all of those 100Kbytes of low-prio data will be sent completely?

Comment: Depends on the scheduling algorithm.  After each frame is transmitted, the queues are checked. If your algorithm says, "service the hi prio queue first, before all others," then the frame in that queue will be transmitted next.  There are different algorithms to prevent the high prio queue from starving other queues.

Comment: Do You have any references where it is explicitly written that qdisc queues contain frames? Is there a way to check which frames were sent first (either on sender or receiver side)?

Comment: 1.   No, but I assume queues contain packets fragmented for the outgoing interface.  2. I guess you could tell by source port, since that's what you're classifying on.

Comment: BTW, the largest IPv4 packet is 64Kbytes.